# How to pass a smart pointer to a function expecting a raw pointer?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have the following code:

```
unsigned char* frame_buffer_data{ new unsigned char[data_size] };
glReadPixels(origin_x, origin_y, width, height, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame_buffer_data);
```

I want to get rid of the raw pointer (`frame_buffer_data`) and use a unique pointer.

Trying this:

```
std::unique_ptr<unsigned char> framebuffer_data(new unsigned char[data_size] );
```

does not work.

How can I pass the unique pointer (or other smart pointer) to this function?

After the call to `glReadPixels` I need to be able to `reinterpret cast` the data type and write the data to a file, like so:

```
screenshot.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(frame_buffer_data), data_size);
```

Comment: Does not work how? Are you getting a compilation error? Which error?

Comment: I'd look at a `std::vector` first, rather than a smart pointer. Also, this will call the wrong version of `delete`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you need an array owned by a smart pointer, you should use `unique_ptr<T[]>`.

```
std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> framebuffer_data(new unsigned char[data_size] );
glReadPixels(origin_x, origin_y, width, height, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, framebuffer_data.get());
```

But better case is like below, it is cleaner and shorter.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> framebuffer_data(data_size);
glReadPixels(origin_x, origin_y, width, height, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &framebuffer_data[0]);
```

Comment: or better yet: [`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) ;)

Comment: nitpick: `framebuffer_data` or `frame_buffer_data`. My preference: `std::vector<unsigned char> frame_buffer ... frame_buffer.data()`